# Mocking GuzzleHttp\Client for testing Lumen route

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, lumen, guzzle

I have the a simple Lumen application using the following two files, that upon requesting the root route `/` it makes a request to get a URL using `GuzzleHttp\Client`:

`routes/web.php`

```
<?php

$router->get('/', ['uses' => 'MyController@index', 'as' => 'index']);
```

`app/Http/Controllers/MyController`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyController extends Controller {
    protected $client;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->client = new Client();
    }

    public function index( Request $request ) {
        $response = $this->client->request( 'get', 'https://www.google.com/' );
        return Response()->json( [ 'status' => $response->getStatusCode() ] );
    }
}
```

However, I want to write a test in which `$response->getStatusCode()` will return `444`, so I wrote the following test, trying to mock `getStatusCode()` method in `GuzzleHttp\Client`:

```
<?php

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class MyTest extends TestCase {
    protected $instance;

    public function testMyRoute() {
        $client = Mockery::mock( Client::class )
                         ->shouldReceive( 'getStatusCode' )
                         ->once()
                         ->andReturn( 444 );
        $this->app->instance( Client::class, $client );

        $this->json( 'get', '/' )->seeJson( [ 'status' => 444 ] );
    }

    public function tearDown() {
        parent::tearDown();
        Mockery::close();
    }
}
```

But running `phpunit` fails:

```
~/experiment/lumen-test/testing » phpunit                                                                                                                                 
PHPUnit 5.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

F                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 868 ms, Memory: 14.00MB

There was 1 failure:

1) MyTest::testMyRoute
Unable to find JSON fragment ["status":444] within [{"status":200}].
Failed asserting that false is true.

~/experiment/lumen-test/testing/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php:288
~/experiment/lumen-test/testing/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php:213
~/experiment/lumen-test/testing/tests/MyTest.php:15

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 2, Failures: 1.
```

That indicates that mocking did not take any effect.  What am I missing here?

#### Edit -1

After modifying `MyController` constructor as per @sam's comment [Mocking GuzzleHttp\Client for testing Lumen route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49757488/mocking-guzzlehttp-client-for-testing-lumen-route/49757710#49757710), I modified the test to be as follows:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;
```

-

```
public function testMyRoute() {
    $response = new Response(444);
    $client = Mockery::mock( Client::class )
                     ->makePartial()
                     ->shouldReceive( 'request' )
                     ->once()
                     ->andReturn( $response );
    $this->app->instance( Client::class, $client );

    $this->json( 'get', '/' )->seeJson( [ 'status' => 444 ] );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're instantiating the `Client` in your constructor which means that it's not being resolved out of the container. Your controller should accept the `Client` as a parameter in the constructor, which will be resolved out of the container by Laravel.

```
public function __construct(Client $client = null) {
    $this->client = $client ?: new Client;
}
```

This will only create a new `Client` if one has not been provided.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container#resolving

> **Automatic Injection**
>
> Alternatively, and importantly, you may "type-hint" the dependency in the constructor of a class that is resolved by the container, including controllers, event listeners, queue jobs, middleware, and more. In practice, this is how most of your objects should be resolved by the container.

Comment: Wow! that was completely absent from me.  After modifying the constructor as in your suggestion, it made sense to update the test a bit too, so I updated the question.  But now it's failing with this message `Invalid JSON was returned from the route. Perhaps an exception was thrown?`

Comment: @MMSs That's because you're not returning any JSON. You've created a `Response` object with a status code of `444` but no body. The third parameter is the body of the response (and the second is the headers). You should do something like: `$response = new Response(444, [], '{"greeting":"Hello World!"}');`

Comment: I figured what was the issue, I had to call `getMock()` in the end of `Mockery::mock` chain to return the mocked class, the `$response = new Response(444)` was good enough to get the required behaviour in my test case.